# Unity Video Player how to get currently displayed frame?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, buffer, video-player

I am working on a synced watching project, a project that enables users to connect into a room in my program and watch the same video synced.
To play the video I am using the `Video Player` component from Unity.
When the **loaded frames** in one of the user clients' are about to end (the video soon has to pause and load the video), the client will send a request to server to pause the video for everyone until the video load the necessary frames.

My problem is that there is no "buffer" attribute or "GetLastLoadedFrame" method or etc, to let me check if the **client's loaded frames is about to end**.

How can I find what is the last loaded frame in Unity's video player component?

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity's VideoPlayer functionality is pretty bare-bones. You could potentially constantly keep track of each VideoPlayer.time attribute, and send a request to the server to pause if any of them fall more than, say, 5 seconds behind, and keep things synchronized that way?